# Issues with #import and @class cause _OBJC_CLASS_ referenced from error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, class, interface

I have two classes.

### APPagine.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface APPagineMedia : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Immagine;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Video;
@end

@interface APPagineDescription : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Descrizione;
@end

@interface APPagineSommarioLinee : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Description;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int IdLinea;
@end

@interface APPagineSommarioCategorie : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Nome;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int DestId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) APPagineSommarioLinee *Linee;
@end

@interface APPagineSommario : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) APPagineSommarioCategorie *Categorie;
@end

@interface APPagine : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *Layout;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int Indice;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Titolo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) APPagineMedia *Media;
@property (nonatomic, retain) APPagineDescription *Descrizione;
@property (nonatomic, retain) APPagineSommario *Sommario;
@end
```

### APXmlData.h

```
@interface APXmlData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Lingua;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float Versione;
@property (nonatomic, assign) long long Timestamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) APPagine    *Pagine;
@property (nonatomic, retain) APCategorie *Categorie;
@property (nonatomic, retain) APCarousel  *Carousel;

@end
```

---

and finally in my controller interface:

```
#import "APXmlData.h"
@interface APViewController : UIViewController
{
  APXmlData *_XmlData;
}
@end
```

and in implementation:

```
_XmlData.Timestamp = 123;
_XmlData.Version = 1.0;
_XmlData.Pagine = [[APPagine alloc] init];
_XmlData.Pagine.Layout = @"a";
_XmlData.Pagine.Indice = 1;
_XmlData.Pagine.Titolo = @"titolo";
//[...]
```

---

But,
in when i go to set data to

```
_XmlData.Pagine = [[APPagine alloc] init];
```

he returns me a linker error, the classic

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_APPagineDescription", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in APPagine.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_APPagineMedia", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in APViewController.o
>         objc-class-ref in APPagine.o
>
> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_APPagineSommario", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in APPagine.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)

My question is: **what is correct way to `import` the classes in my controller?**
Should be use `#import` or `@class`?
In that order?
What are the classes that require `@class` or `#import`?

### NOTE

In **Build -> Compile Sources**, both files are properly configured.
If i remove `_XmlData.Pagine = [[APPagine alloc] init];` the apps run well

thanks.

Comment: this linker error may also appear if ur build phases doesn't have respective xib's or implementation files, can u check that wthr some thing is missing..

Comment: The xib in not important, i have only the controller. If i remove `_XmlData.Pagine = [[APPagine alloc] init];` the apps run well.

Comment: You say the compile sources is ok. Are the .m files with the `@implementation` for `APPagineDescription`, etc., included, too?

Comment: You show all of those `@interface` statements, but that has absolutely nothing to do with the linker error. The question is where are the corresponding `@implementation` clauses? Are those .m files for those included in the "Build Settings"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you receive is a linker error, not a compiler error, so it looks like your `#import` was done correctly. Linker errors occur when the program linker cannot find the implementation. I would suggest that you check:

- That you have the corresponding `@implementation` in e.g. APPagine.m
- That APPagine.m is included in the project and active for your target in XCode

Comment: +1 thanks man, adding @implementation in APPagine works well. But is mandatory? Or it's important only when I add multiple interfaces?

Comment: The `@implementation` is where you implement the methods for a class. If you are looking to create a pure interface (protocol in ObjC), you should use `@protocol` instead of `@interface`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your viewController has just

```
#import "APXmlData.h"
```

as you are using `_XmlData.Pagine = [[APPagine alloc] init];` in your viewController

you should also import `APPagine` class in your viewController, using

```
#import "APPagine.h"
```

Comment: I don't think so. That might be the right solution if he was getting a compiler error, but he's not. It's a linker error, which means he hasn't included some portion of the `APPagine` class, itself, in his project.

Comment: @vishy -- Possibly true but it wouldn't give him a linker error.  That's a sign of a missing implementation.

Comment: yeah i think these are only 2 reasons causes this error.. i have suggested both, lets which one will fix it..

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have a linker error means that the problem is not with your `#import` or `@class` declarations. The problem is that your project is missing either the .m files for this class (in case the library includes source that you're supposed to compile yourself) or the library (.a or .dylib or .framework, if the library was already compiled for you). Check the "Build Phases" in your target settings to make sure the necessary files have been included in the project.